# How can i perform PUT request using ajax and jquery in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-models

I have been struggling for hours trying to update my database in django using PUT request. I'm gathering my data from a form and I want to update a database entry based on the text which the user types. I specifically have to use PUT request method but I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here I am getting the data from the form:

```js
        $("#modify-btn").click(function(){
            console.log('modify pressed')
            $.ajax({
                url : "{% url 'modify item' %} ",
                method : "POST",
                data: $("#detailsForm").serializeArray(),
                success : function (data) {
                    console.log(data.id,data.name,data.brand,data.model)
                    /////
                    $.ajax({ /// this is where i need to use the PUT request
                        url : 
                    })



                    ///
                }
            })

        })
```

This is my views.py file:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template import loader
from phonemodels.models import Phone

def index(request):
    return render(request,'phonemodels/index.html',{
        'phones' : Phone.objects.all(),
    })

def items_json(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        'phones' : list(Phone.objects.values())
    })

def new_item(request):
    phone_name = request.POST['Brand']
    phone_model = request.POST['Model']
    phone_price = request.POST['Price']
    phone = Phone (brandName=phone_name,phoneModel=phone_model,phonePrice=phone_price)
    phone.save()
    return JsonResponse({
        'id' : phone.id,
        'brand': phone.brandName,
        'model' : phone.phoneModel,
        'price' : phone.phonePrice

    })
def modify_item(request):
    phone_name = request.POST['BrandModify']
    phone_model = request.POST['ModelModify']
    phone_price = request.POST['PriceModify']
    phone = Phone.objects.get(brandName=phone_name,phoneModel=phone_model,phonePrice=phone_price)
    phone.id
    return JsonResponse({
        'id' : phone.id,
        'name': phone_name,
        'brand': phone_model,
        'model' : phone_price
        })
```

Comment: i am using POST in order to get the data from the form. Once I got the data i want to use PUT.

Comment: Will need to be a lot more specific about the exact problem(s) you are having

Comment: I have no clue how to implement a PUT request

Comment: As far as front end goes (`$.ajax`) you do it same way as you are doing the POST but change  `method` to `'PUT'`

Comment: I have tried, however I get this : "403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: OK well that was never mentioned in question (and should be as should all errors encountered).

Comment: As with the POST request, you will need to include the CSRF token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That 403 is caused by a CSRF exception.

Nonetheless, if you want to make a `PUT` request it should be fairly simple:

1. You're sending an `$.ajax` request with method `PUT`

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    method: 'PUT'
})
```

2. You're handling the `PUT` request in your function based view but you gotta make sure that it is wrapped with [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator:

```
 path('your-url/', csrf_exempt(modify_item), name='modify-item-url')
```

I strongly advise you look into [Django's CBV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)